# Hardcoding of path and how to avoid it?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

spring-boot-starter-parent 2.3.5.RELEASE

I'm studying a video course. Thymeleaf it used. The lecturer has hardcoded a part of a path.

```
<a hredf="#" th:href="@{/recipe/show} + ${recipe.id}}">View</a>
```

Could you tell me whether such hardcoding is Ok? Why didn't they put this path to a variable and didn't pass it to the context?

Is there a way not to hardcode paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this kind of links are usually immutable.
like for showing receipts id.
and hard coding them aint a problem.

but if your path can be change, you can change use a variable like what you have done:

```
${recipe.id}
```

if you had another *variable* section in your path you could use variable for them too.

```
<a hredf="#" th:href="@{/recipe/} + ${actionName} + ${recipe.id}">View</a>
```

There is some kind of *not to hard coding* in Spring (JSF) to use ControllerName and Action Name as route name like this:

```
<h:commandButton action = "#{receiptController.show}" />
```

or:

```
<h:commandLink action = "#{receiptController.show}" value = "link text">
  <f:param name = "receiptId" value = "${receipt.id}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

According to : https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html

thymeleaf has not implement This Feature.

you can only pass variables to it.

so you can have an static class of Constant url map.

Comment: There are a lot of such links. Should I organize a special class for keeping such url constants for the whole projects?

Comment: normally you dosent need something like that.in some frameworks like php-laravel there is this structure named **route name** that you can assign a name to each path (route) and using the names. relation between route names and actual paths are stored in a file.

Comment: but most of the case. the paths are immutable and even you want to change them in code you can use Find&Replace Feature of an Editor to Achieve this

Comment: but in parts of URI which using a variable part. you have to use variables. like an entity id (receipt.id) or a search term.

Comment: The variable part can be part of URi or can be part of query string.

Comment: Yes, I need something like named route name. Why do you consider urls immutable? They may be perfectly mutable. If a project manager tells you that now the specification changes and urls will be different, then it changes. And even if it does not, I don't like hardcoding and repeatitions. Why should I repeat the same path in the controller and in the template? I don't like it at all. And the idea of finding and replacing is not that attractive.